# PHP routing system for social site

Tags: php, mysql, url

I've been reading about social sites, and I've seen Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook etc. a few to mention. These sites like other sites use some type of routing to load different modules depending on the site url.

E.g. http://www.something.com/notificiation/{id}

The above url would load the module that takes care of notifications and given an {id} it would render and return a specific notification with deeper details.

Can anyone possibly guide me through routing or point me to a site which actually teaches this. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate all of your support and help in advance.

EDIT: Nice urls with .htaccess is not a problem, I know this part already. I am curious about the routing part itself.

Comment: Routing in the pure technical sense is simply "taking action based on the contents of the requesting URL". That's all it is at the core. There are lots (and lots) of libraries and frameworks that take care of this for you. A quick google will turn them up.

Comment: @Bulk I know. I also know that one can do it this way: $current_url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($current_url);

Comment: how this works for the majority of php sites, is a .htaccess file redirects all requests to a single 'controller', which then acts upon the route configured for each path

Comment: @JohnSmith Okay? So what are you asking then? SO isn't google - if you have a specific technical question, ask it.

Comment: I explained what routing is, thats literally it - there is no more. The rest is just implementation - of which there are countless ways (and their discussion is incredibly off topic for SO)

Comment: I am out for a recommended way (I am aware how this sounds, there's no right or wrong).

Comment: Well *my* recommended way would be to use a framework, Laravel, Symfony, Zend etc - take your pick. If you must have a standalone library, Symfony's routing package (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) would be a very good start.

Comment: But I am already writing a php framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` files and rewriting will be your friend. This would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/notification/(.*)$ getNotification.php?id=$1 [L]
```

For the Basics of .htaccess files, you can use Google - there is a lot out there.

But for some good snippets I would recommend [this](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess) :)

Comment: Then what are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

You sanitize the ID value and put it into a variable. Then use this variable in say a switch statement to load modules or redirect to another URL. The ID may be available in say the $_GET variable.

Comment: can you show me an example? E.g. how this is done with parameters excluding .htaccess.

Comment: Given a .htaccess rewrite to say: getNotification.php?id=$1 The ID can be obtained with: $id = $_GET['id']; Then have switch($id) {case "module1": include "module1.php"; break}

Comment: Let's say no .htaccess has been configured. I want to go old style, like back in the old days. Think the web in the early days.

Comment: So the old school URL was like index.php?page=twitter And in the index.php code could have: if ($_GET['page'] == "twitter") include twitter.php;

Comment: John - maybe you don't realize that in the old days, the URLs ending in say .htm could not run (server-side) scripts, they had to end in say .pl or .cgi Now we use ,htaccess to cover up the destination script URL with a nice keyword URL

Answer (score 1):

Will try to explain. Assume that:

1. The request is made to `http://www.example.com/index.php`
2. If `mod_rewrite` (Apache) is enabled and the URL will be rewritten, e.g. `http://www.example.com`
3. The `index.php` still has the request available, processing it

   ```
   $uri = Router::make_uri();

   if ($params = Router::match_uri($uri))
   {
       $controller = ucwords($params['controller']).'_Controller';
       $method = $params['method'];

       unset($params['controller'], $params['method']);

       if (class_exists($controller) && method_exists($controller, $method))
       {
           call_user_func_array(array(new $controller, $method), $params);
       }
   }
   ```
4. The `Router` class

   ```
   private static $routes;

   public static $uri;

   public static $segment;

   public static function make_uri()
   {
       if(!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
       {
           self::$uri = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
       }
       elseif (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
       {
           self::$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

           if (defined('INDEX') && is_file(INDEX))
           {
               $index_file = INDEX;
           }
           else
           {
               $index_file = 'index.php';
           }

           //removing index
           if (strpos(self::$uri, $index_file) !== FALSE)
           {
               self::$uri = str_replace(self::$uri, $index_file, '');
           }
       }

       return parse_url(trim(self::$uri, '/'), PHP_URL_PATH);
   }

   public static function match_uri($uri)
   {
       require(APP_DIR.DIR_SEP.'system'.DIR_SEP.'config'.DIR_SEP.'Routes.php');

       if (empty($routes))
       {
           Error::throw_error('Routes must not be empty');
       }

       self::$routes = $routes;

       $params = array();

       foreach ($routes as $route)
       {
           //we keep our route uri in the [0] position
           $route_uri = array_shift($route);

           $regex_uri = self::make_regex_uri($route_uri);

           if (!preg_match($regex_uri, $uri, $match))
           {
               continue;
           }
           else
           {               
               foreach ($match as $key => $value)
               {
                   if (is_int($key))
                   {
                       //removing preg_match digit keys
                       continue;
                   }

                   $params[$key] = $value;
               }

               //if no values are set, load default ones
               foreach ($route as $key => $value)
               {
                   if (!isset($params[$key]))
                   {
                       $params[$key] = $value;
                   }
               }

               break;
           }
       }

       return $params;
   }

   private static function make_regex_uri($uri)
   {
       $reg_escape = '[.\\+*?[^\\]${}=!|]';
       $expression = preg_replace('#'.$reg_escape.'#', '\\\\$0', $uri);

       if (strpos($expression, '(') !== FALSE)
       {
           $expression = str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('(?:', ')?'), $expression);
       }

       $reg_segment = '[^/.,;?\n]++';
       $expression = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('(?P<', '>'.$reg_segment.')'), $expression);

       return '#^'.$expression.'$#uD';
   }

   public static function make_url($route_name = '', $params = array())
   {
       if (!$routes = self::$routes)
       {
           require(APP_DIR.DIR_SEP.'system'.DIR_SEP.'config'.DIR_SEP.'Routes.php');
       }

       if (!in_array($route_name, array_keys($routes)))
       {
           return BASE_URL;
       }
       else
       {
           $route = $routes[$route_name];
           $uri = array_shift($route);

           //replace given params
           foreach ($params as $key => $value)
           {
               $string = '<'.$key.'>';
               if (strpos($uri, $string) !== FALSE)
               {
                   $uri = str_replace($string, $value, $uri);
               }
           }

           //replace initial params
           if (strpos($uri, '<') !== FALSE)
           {
               foreach ($route as $key => $value)
               {
                   $string = '<'.$key.'>';
                   if (strpos($uri, $string) !== FALSE)
                   {
                       $uri = str_replace($string, $value, $uri);
                   }
               }
           }

           //if any undefined variable exists return BASE_URL
           if (strpos($uri, '<') !== FALSE)
           {
               return BASE_URL;
           }
           else
           {
               return rtrim(BASE_URL.str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $uri), '/');
           }
       }
   }

   public static function get_segment($segment = TRUE)
   {
       if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
       {
           $segments = explode('/', self::make_uri());

           $segments_count = count($segments);

           if ($segment === TRUE || $segment >= $segments_count || $segment < 0)
           {
               return self::$segment = $segments[$segments_count - 1];
           }
           else
           {
               return self::$segment = $segments[$segment];
           }
       }
       else
       {
           return FALSE;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Explained: the current `uri` is made (`make_uri`) basing on data `_SERVER` variable contains. Assuming that `BASE_URL` is `http://www.example.com` the `make_uri` will return empty string `''`
6. The `uri` is matched against a preset rules aka `Routes`. Example, `Routes.php`

   ```
   $routes['home'] = array(
   '',
   'controller' => 'main',
   'method' => 'home'
   );
   ```
7. If the matching route is found (for this particular case the `''` pattern) the `params` are sanitized (removed the `preg_match` redundancies) and returned (an array of Controller, Method and Method parameters) in order to `enter code here`. In this case, the `http://www.example.com` will be handled by `Main_Controller`, method `home` with no method parameters provided.

Comment: Let's forget the controller part, here's another question of mine, does one have to predefine what GET param to support in advanced?

Comment: IMHO, it depends on the framework/scripts. In the case above, no - the $_GET is passed on untouched.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 stages to this.

**Stage 1**

Vanity URLS which can be achieved with a `.htaccess` rewrite rule. For example, we take the vanity URL and rewrite it to load our controller - which in turn loads our model and view.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/notification/(0-9*)$ index.php?controller=notification&action=getNotification&id=$1 [L]
```

**Stage 2**

A good design pattern - such as MVC - will be able to get route our request nicely. Our router would look something like this (this will be more PHP psuedo code, but you get the idea).

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['controller']) ) {
  if( Utils::ControllerExists( $_GET['controller'].'Controller.php' ) ) {
      $objController = Utils::LoadController( $_GET['controller'].'Controller.php' );

      //Check the method exists 
      if( method_exists($objController, $_GET['action']) ) {
          //Simple method. But will need to know the parameters needed.
          $strOutput = $objController->{$_GET['action']}({$_GET['id']});
          Utils::LoadView('HTML', $strOutput);
          die;
      }

  } 
}

//Redirect to default page?
Utils::Redirect('home');
die;
```

Our controller will then look like;

```
<?php

class notificationController {

   public function getNotification($intNotificationId) {
        //Query database for notification
        return $return_value;
   }
}
```

### However...

It may be beneficial to you to use an existing Framework that handles routing (and other crucial elements), such as;

- [Lithium](http://li3.me)
- [Laravel](http://laravel.com)
- [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com)